# How SQOOP detects the driver class while importing data?

Tags: teradata, sqoop, amazon-emr

While doing `sqoop-import` I have seen that -

- In case of **mysql** we don't need to **explicitly** specify mysql driver class using `--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. There were also no extra jars needed.
- This is same for **oracle** or **db2** also. But I have to add 1 jar for oracle and 3 jars for db2 in *$SQOOP_HOME* to make the connection.

But when I came across with **teradata** I have to add 2 jars and if I don’t specify ***driver class***, sqoop is trowing error.

So I have to explicitly mention `--driver com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver`

> Is there somewhere these are all mentioned in sqoop?
>
> OR
>
> sqoop is smart enough to identify the driver class for db2 and oracle? 
>   If so why it is failing in case of teradata.

I have also noticed one thing in EMR cluster config.
A property called `sqoop.connection.factories=com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory` in `sqoop-site.xml`.

> Is this doing sometime?

Comment: The sqoop distribution includes some driver jars (e.g. MySQL) and there is specific logic for certain databases (not Teradata, currently). Otherwise for a connection string that starts `jdbc:XXX:...` the default is to look for `com.XXX.jdbc.driver`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that `com.cloudera.sqoop.manager.DefaultManagerFactory` class implementation of those configs. [github](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/manager/DefaultManagerFactory.java)